# org-encrypt-entry doesn't work

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, encryption

Below is debugger results. epa does work fwiw.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Encrypt failed")
  signal(error ("Encrypt failed"))
  error("Encrypt failed")
  org-encrypt-entry()
  funcall-interactively(org-encrypt-entry)
  call-interactively(org-encrypt-entry record nil)
  command-execute(org-encrypt-entry record)
  helm-M-x(nil #("org-encrypt-entry" 0 17 (match-part "org-encrypt-entry")))
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil #("org-encrypt-entry" 0 17 (match-part "org-encrypt-entry")))
  call-interactively(helm-M-x nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)
```

Comment: It probably failed while running gpg or gpg2. Are there any messages about it in the *Messages* buffer?

Comment: Only 'org-encrypt-entry: Encrypt failed'

Comment: That message comes from `epg-encrypt-string`. Try debugging that function in file epg.el.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem -- for me the private key set up for the encryption was expired.

```
# First try whether you can encrpyt anything from the command line
touch /tmp/test.txt
gpg --encrypt --recipient "your_mailaddress@example.org" /tmp/test.txt
```

This failed for me with `/tmp/test.txt: encryption failed: No public key` (which I found slightly misleading). But `gpg --list-keys` showed me that my key was indeed expired. So I changed the expire-date to be in one year:

```
gpg --quick-set-expire "your_mailaddress@example.org" 1y
```

Now `gpg --encrypt --recipient "your_mailaddress@example.org" /tmp/test.txt` worked as well as the `org-encrypt-entry`. Maybe that is your problem as well?

Comment: Worked! I had to do even more configuration to get it all going, including installing pinentry-mac (via brew) for decryption. Thanks @ricma